# convert doesn't conserve size when scaling down and up

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

In order to make applying blur faster I'm first scaling my image down and then scale it back up:

```
convert - -scale 10% -blur 0x2.5 -resize 1000% RGB:-
```

This works most of the time but sometimes the output resolution is slightly different from the original input. Is there a way to force the pipeline to be size-preserving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to access the original geometry of the image via [%G](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php), so you can do:

```
convert input.jpg -scale 10% -blur 0x2.5 -resize '%G!' RGB:-
```

If you are using **Windows**, you probably want `"%G!"` in double rather than single quotes.

If you are using v7 **ImageMagick**, replace `convert` with `magick`.

---

I think you are getting errors because if you take 10% of 72 pixels (say), you will get a whole number of pixels, i.e. 7 pixels and then when you scale back up by a factor of 10 you'll get 70 rather than your initial 72.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Imagemagick 7, you can do the following:

```
magick input.jpg -set option:wd "%w" -set option:ht "%h" -scale "%[fx:wd/10]x%[fx:ht/10]" -blur 0x2.5 -resize "%[fx:wd]x%[fx:ht]\!" RGB:-
```

This stores the input width and height. Then uses the stored values to scale by 1/10 of those dimensions, then does the blur, then resizes exactly back to the origin input size. Note the ! that forces the resize to the exact dimensions.

or simpler without storing the input width and height:

```
magick lena.jpg -scale "%[fx:w/10]x%[fx:h/10]" -blur 0x2.5 -resize "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]\!" lena_x.jpg
```